# Display UIActivityIndicatorView whilst UI is updating

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I have an app which renders "pages" of content made up from sets of controls (UIWebViews plus a set of custom controls). This processing currently takes around 1 second to complete and locks up the UI whilst processing.

I can't move the building of the UI elements onto a background thread as I'm using UIWebView so this is to some extent unavoidable (I am only loading pages on demand as needed).

Wat I what to do is show an activity indicator whilst the content is being rendered, but I can't seem to make this happen. I have tried setting up an indicator and then triggering the method that renders the rest of the content after a very brief delay, but this is never reflected in the UI.

Does anyone have any examples of triggering an activity indicator prior to a CPU heavy rendering operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need MbProgressHUD, a very simple way to add progress indicator... It saved me a lot of trouble.

https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

Comment: Looks like that requires work to be done on a background thread? As I said, it looks like you can't do anything with UIWebView on anything other than the main thread.

Comment: It doesn't require a background thread. You use the first WebViews shouldStartLoadWithRequest and clean it up in didFinishLoad in the last of your series. It will work. Used it many times and it is fast and easy to setup.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I have understood well but if you just want to add an activity indicator
you can use the uiwebview delegate's methods. For example you can add your activity indicator view in shouldStartLoadWithRequest and remove it in didFinishLoad.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, the thing that is rendering isn't just a webview, it is a set of webviews and other controls.